# Conditional string formatting

Tags: c#, string, conditional-statements, string.format

I'm trying to use conditional string format in order to show records found or not like this
"5 of 10 rows found"

```
string msg = "{0:#;;} of {1:#;;} {2:rows;no rows;row} found";
return string.Format(msg, searchItems, totalItems, totalItems - 1);
```

Everything works very well until totalItems is 0 because then I got the message set like this.
"  of  no rows found"  (WRONG)

I would like something like this
"no rows found"

```
searchItems = 0 ; totalItems = 0 ==> "no rows found"

searchItems = 1 ; totalItems = 1 ==> "1 row found"

searchItems = 2 ; totalItems = 5 ==> "2 of 5 rows found"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a `.ToString()` to the `searchItems` variable, e.g:

```
string msg = "{0:#;;} of {1:#;;} {2:rows;no rows;row} found";
return string.Format(msg, searchItems.ToString(), totalItems, totalItems - 1);
```

Assuming `searchItems` and `totalItems` are both `0`:

> 0 of no rows found

Assuming `searchItems` and `totalItems` are both `1`:

> 1 of 1 row found

Assuming `searchItems` is `2` and `totalItems` is `5`:

> 2 of 5 rows found

However, I would rewrite this and use an if statement, which may be more lines of code, but is **far** more readable.

Comment: I would really like something like this for no rows: "no rows found" more than "0 of no rows found" but seriously it solved my problem. Thank you so much!